# AWS Node.js Lambda Invoking Lambda Failing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The AWS Lambda.invoke command seems to do nothing for me. It neither throws an error nor returns. I've read tonnes of posts and I think have all the ARN right. But since the 'invoke' never happens, I assume this is an ARN issue? Any ideas?

Code:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var params = {
        FunctionName: 'myfunction',
        InvocationType: 'Event',
        LogType: 'Tail',
        Payload: '{"sample_param": "payload_string"}'
    };

    lambda.invoke(params, function(err,data){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error");
        } else {
            console.log("Returned: " + data.Payload);
        }
    });
};
```

This returns:

[image]

ARN / Policies:

[image]

Solution, I'm an idiot and didn't use a promise:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    var params = {
        FunctionName: 'my_fuction',
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        Payload: '{"my_param": "my_value"}'
    };

    return lambda.invoke(params).promise();
};
```

Comment: 1. Is either lambda in a VPC?  2. Using the `Event` Invocation Type means that this process will not wait for the response (even though you're providing a callback).  You can change that to `RequestResponse` for debugging purposes.

Comment: I've tried with both. I only used Event to start because I plan on using it later. Regardless, I've checked the cloudwatch logs and it's never being invoked at all. Neither is on a VPC.

Comment: 1. Can you take the `LogType` off? 2. Is all of your stuff running in `us-east-1` ?

Comment: 1. Yes, same response. 2. Yup. Just to make sure I double checked my ARNs. All on us-east-1

Comment: You should get an error if anything is wrong with either the ARN or the permissions.  But I do notice... don't you need to return a promise from the handler? Otherwise the invoker of your handler (the Lambda service) thinks you're done? 
 https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks!